# How to work with encrypt database?

Tags: php, yii

I have a new type project. Please help if you can. I have a user management project in which i have many tables lets say user table.

table user
fields user_id , user_f_name , user_l_name, user_username.. etc. this table is encrypted in real like

RM_999(this is name of encrypted table)
RM_0999, RM_1999 , RM_2999 , RM_3999... 
I the same manner all tables and columns are encrypted for sake of security.

But i have yii project written in simple names like user_username (As it was already made project which i used for variouus project). But now i don't want to changed my code for that encrpted database. Is there is any way bye which i can use my written code without changing it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your existing application code is written.

The below approach may solve your problem

In your project, if there are entity classes for all tables in DB which extends CActiveRecord then you can use attributeLables() so that you can map  your existing column names to encrypted column names. (Assumed that your application code access that table attributes via labels).